# Is there a way to let Git not use internationalized strings in commit messages?

Tags: git, internationalization

I recently updated Git to 2.7.0 via fink on my mac os x (10.9.5). By default the build is internationalized. This is fine for interacting with Git via `git status` and the like commands, but is a bit annoying when doing commits, as it applies to things like "renamed", "modified", "deleted", which I am in the habit of un-commenting when editing the commit message. I don't like that my repos will suddenly have the French words after hundreds of commits with the English ones.

I did a "fink rebuild git" after hiding the `libintl.h` file, the resulting `git` then has no internationalization. Problem is, in the meantime I had gotten used to `--date=format:%c` in an alias I have for a pretty log, this has the effect of localizing the displayed dates in the `git log` output.

I would like to:

1. still be able to tell git to display dates in `git log ...` commands in a way obeying my locale,
2. but at the same time not have the words like "deleted", "modified" pre-translated in the pre-edited commit messages.

Is the only way perhaps to modify `po/fr.po` in a local clone of the git repo ? But this would then defeat the advantages of having done the installation via fink (as I am not following Git development, I don't have much interest in keeping a clone on my disc).

Comment: Does `LANG= git <command>` help?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I had tried that but doing ``alias git="LANG=en_US.UTF-8 git"``  defeats the `--date=format:%c` for my variant of `git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate ...` (from `git help log`: *Use --date=format:%c to show the date in your system locale’s preferred format.*). However, I could possibly do an alias ``alias gitcommit ="LANG=en_US.UTF-8 git commit"``, ... yes that could fix my problem which is primarily with `git commit`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk the idea of my previous comment will however have issues for merge commits for example, they will not escape internationalization. It is really needed, in my opinion, to have some way to let Git interact with the user in a locale obeying way, but keep English for all repo related things, as anyhow this repo may be in need to be shared with developers of another native language.

Answer (score 0):

This self-answer will hopefully be superseded by a better, regular, answer.

In the meantime, for lack of a better method, I am currently experimenting with this  in `.bashrc`:

```
alias gitfr="LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 /sw/bin/git"
alias git="LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /sw/bin/git"
```

The `gitfr` alias will serve me in commands like:

```
foo$ gitfr log --date=format:%c
commit 22e01a35803f2b70a3e413d2fc9c774baffa01cc
Author: jfbu <...>
Date:   Mar  2 fév 10:18:10 2016

    OK
```

Notice the French localized date. This is about the only place in using Git where I am keen on seeing French. The problem I have with the French translations in
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/po/fr.po is that they make it into pre-formatted commit messages. This is annoying because perhaps in the future some words will be translated otherwise upstream, or I will want to work on my own forked translations, but things like `Validation initiale` will have made it into the commit history. This causes problems if the repo is to be maintained by other developers, not French, at a later date.

Imagine the symmetric situation with me examining a repo which has been maintained for a while on a Chinese `zh_CN` localized system. For example some commit was about modified or removed files, and the committer uncommented while editing the commit message the git prepared lines saying it. If later on I examine the commit history and I am confronted with Chinese ideograms, I will not know immediately if the file was modifed, added, or removed.

Thus, still looking for a solution to:

1. use localized git for command-line interaction,
2. but keep all commit history in English.